# haskell parse error on input "="

Tags: haskell

```
quicksort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
quicksort [] = []
quicksort (x:xs) =
    let smallerOrEqual = [a | a <- xs, a <= x]
        larger = [a | a <- xs, a > x]
    in quicksort smallerOrEqual ++ [x] += larger

main = do
    a = [ 5, 1, 9, 4, 6, 7, 3]
    print quicksort a
```

I got this error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( quicksort.hs, quicksort.o )

quicksort.hs:10:11: parse error on input `='
```

Really don't undrestand why. Double checked this code several times. Still confusing.
Need help.
thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot a `let`,

```
quicksort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
quicksort [] = []
quicksort (x:xs) =
    let smallerOrEqual = [a | a <- xs, a <= x]
        larger = [a | a <- xs, a > x]
    in quicksort smallerOrEqual ++ [x] ++ quicksort larger -- ++ not +=

main = do
    let a = [ 5, 1, 9, 4, 6, 7, 3]
    print (quicksort a) -- The parens are needed too
```

I fixed a few other errors too.

It's worth noting that this quicksort isn't in place and therefore is not really quicksort, though it is pretty.

Comment: Yeah, this `quickSort` implementation is pretty much Haskell's signature code snippet since it's so pretty.

Comment: Shouldnt it be `in (quicksort smallerOrEqual) ++ [x] ++ (quicksort larger)` ?

Comment: @ssm Function application has the highest precedence, it doesn't matter

Comment: why is this not real quicksort? Not in place ? require more spaces,right? Other than that, this still implements quick sort algorithm IMO.

Comment: @NoName No, in place means it requires less space since we don't have to create space for all the temporaries. This is the "essence" of quicksort but the real "quick" in quicksort is partially due to the fact we have to allocate nothing

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart Nope, you just need to use the ST monad, this means you essentially are writing C with a nicer calling interface though :/

Comment: It's true that *one of* quicksort's advantages is that it can be done in-place, but that's certainly not its only advantage—using random pivots makes it use fewer comparisons, on average, than most other sorts. That said, merge sort is very definitely a better fit for Haskell.

Comment: @jozefg ssm was pointing out that `larger` needs to be sorted as well, not that parentheses were missing.

Answer (score 4):

Within `do` blocks, bindings must be preceded by the `let` keyword, so the line should be `let a = [ 5, 1, 9, 4, 6, 7, 3]`.

There are a few other errors, however. You appear to have mistyped the `++` operator and you forgot to sort the larger section of the list. Your print statement won't work because `print quicksort a` is parsed as passing both the function `quickSort` and the value `a` to `print`. You can easily fix this using parentheses or the function application operator (`$`). This code works perfectly:

```
quicksort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
quicksort [] = []
quicksort (x:xs) =
    let smallerOrEqual = [a | a <- xs, a <= x]
        larger = [a | a <- xs, a > x]
    in quicksort smallerOrEqual ++ [x] ++ quickSort larger

main = do
    let a = [ 5, 1, 9, 4, 6, 7, 3]
    print $ quicksort a
```